# Generate a string of names from the 2d array matrix

Tags: javascript

I have a 2d array where I need to generate the report.

The names of employees working is maintained in the schedule, and the replacements for the day is mentioned. So a report needs to be generated and the expected result to be for the sample data is

- Name#1: 24,26 Jan ----> Name#2
- Name#5: 23 - 27 Jan ----> Name#4
- Name#6: 23, 25-27 Jan ----> Name#3

[image]

I have tried using JS, But I am struggling to understand the way it works.

```js
function display() {
const values = [
    ["Name/Date", "2023-01-22T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-23T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-24T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-25T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-26T18:30:00.000Z"],
    ["Name#1", "", "Name#2", "", "Name#2", ""],
    ["Name#2", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["Name#3", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["Name#4", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["Name#5", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4"],
    ["Name#6", "Name#3", "", "Name#3", "Name#3", "Name#3"]
]

for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0]) {
        var string = [];
        for (var j = 1; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            if (values[i][j]) {
                string.push(values[i][j])
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(schedule)
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2d array matrix to string report using js arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298872/2d-array-matrix-to-string-report-using-js-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some checks for the last name.

```js
function display() {
    const
        values = [["Name/Date", "2023-01-22T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-23T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-24T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-25T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-26T18:30:00.000Z"], ["Name#1", "", "Name#2", "", "Name#2", ""], ["Name#2", "", "", "", "", ""], ["Name#3", "", "", "", "", ""], ["Name#4", "", "", "", "", ""], ["Name#5", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4"], ["Name#6", "Name#3", "", "Name#3", "Name#3", "Name#3"]],
        result = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        let row;
        for (let j = 1; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            if (!values[i][j]) continue;
            if (values[i][j - 1] === values[i][j]) {
                row[2] = '-';
                row[3] = values[0][j].slice(0, 10);
            } else {
                const date = values[0][j].slice(0, 10);
                row = [values[i][0], date, ',', date, values[i][j]];
                result.push(row);
            }               
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

console.log(display());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a refactored version of the code to generate the report string as described:

```
function display() {
  const values = [    ["Name/Date", "2023-01-22T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-23T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-24T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-25T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-26T18:30:00.000Z"],
    ["Name#1", "", "Name#2", "", "Name#2", ""],
    ["Name#2", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["Name#3", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["Name#4", "", "", "", "", ""],
    ["Name#5", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4"],
    ["Name#6", "Name#3", "", "Name#3", "Name#3", "Name#3"]
  ]

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var working = [];
    var replacing = "";
    for (var j = 1; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j]) {
        if (!replacing) {
          replacing = values[i][j];
        }
        working.push(j);
      } else if (replacing) {
        console.log(`${values[i][0]}: ${new Date(values[0][working[0]]).toLocaleDateString()} ${working.length > 1 ? "-" : ","} ${new Date(values[0][working[working.length - 1]]).toLocaleDateString()} ----> ${replacing}`);
        working = [];
        replacing = "";
      }
    }
    if (replacing) {
      console.log(`${values[i][0]}: ${new Date(values[0][working[0]]).toLocaleDateString()} ${working.length > 1 ? "-" : ","} ${new Date(values[0][working[working.length - 1]]).toLocaleDateString()} ----> ${replacing}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's an updated version of your code that generates the desired report:

Comment: Its still incorrect, Please see the expected output and your output says https://i.postimg.cc/ZRB0MVcw/image.png The Name#1 shuld be 24,26 Jan ----> Name#2 but your output says 24,24 and 26 and 26. Here the format specified is important and not simply generating the output of dates.