# 2d array matrix to string report using js arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a 2 dimensional array where I need to generate the report.

Expected result

- Name#1: 24,26 Jan ----> Name#2
- Name#5: 23 - 27 Jan ----> Name#4
- Name#6: 23, 25-27 Jan ----> Name#3

The input data

[image]

The names of employees working is maintained in the schedule, and the replacements for the day is mentioned.

I have tried using JS, But I am struggling to understand the way it works.

```js
function display() {
const values = [["Name/Date","2023-01-22T18:30:00.000Z","2023-01-23T18:30:00.000Z","2023-01-24T18:30:00.000Z","2023-01-25T18:30:00.000Z","2023-01-26T18:30:00.000Z"],["Name#1","","Name#2","","Name#2",""],["Name#2","","","","",""],["Name#3","","","","",""],["Name#4","","","","",""],["Name#5","Name#4","Name#4","Name#4","Name#4","Name#4"],["Name#6","Name#3","","Name#3","Name#3","Name#3"]]


for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0]) {
        var string = [];
        for (var j = 1; j < values[i].length; j++) {
            if (values[i][j]) {
                string.push(values[i][j])
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(schedule)
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question / desired output?

Comment: Your table does not match your `values` array. SO the desired outcome can't be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Given your data, you can do this in two loops,

1. gathering all of the replacement dates
2. looping over those per-person replacement dates to find the runs of a single replacement

The final formatting of the date strings to your desired format is left as a separate exercise.

```js
const values = [
  ['Name/Date', '2023-01-22T18:30:00.000Z', '2023-01-23T18:30:00.000Z', '2023-01-24T18:30:00.000Z', '2023-01-25T18:30:00.000Z', '2023-01-26T18:30:00.000Z'],
  ['Name#1', '', 'Name#2', '', 'Name#2', ''],
  ['Name#2', '', '', '', '', ''],
  ['Name#3', '', '', '', '', ''],
  ['Name#4', '', '', '', '', ''],
  ['Name#5', 'Name#4', 'Name#4', 'Name#4', 'Name#4', 'Name#4'],
  ['Name#6', 'Name#3', '', 'Name#3', 'Name#3', 'Name#3'],
];

// Loop over the data to generate a simple mapping of replacements
const replacementsByPersonAndDate = {};
for (let y = 1; y < values.length; y++) {
  let row = values[y];
  const person = row[0];
  for (let x = 1; x < row.length; x++) {
    const date = values[0][x].split('T')[0]; // Just the date
    const replacement = row[x];
    replacementsByPersonAndDate[person] = replacementsByPersonAndDate[person] || {};
    replacementsByPersonAndDate[person][date] = replacement;
  }
}

// Loop over the simple mapping to find runs of replacements, and format
for (let [person, replacements] of Object.entries(replacementsByPersonAndDate)) {
  let currentRun = null;
  let runs = [];
  for (let date of Object.keys(replacements).sort()) {
    const replacement = replacements[date];
    if (!currentRun || replacement !== currentRun.replacement) {
      currentRun = null;
      if (replacement) { // Only start a new run if there is a replacement
        currentRun = {dates: [], replacement};
        runs.push(currentRun);
      }
    }
    if(currentRun) {
      currentRun.dates.push(date);
    }
  }
  for (const {replacement, dates} of runs) {
    if (dates.length > 1) {
      console.log(`${person} replaced by ${replacement} on ${dates[0]} through ${dates[dates.length - 1]}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`${person} replaced by ${replacement} on ${dates[0]}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @CodeGuy I did the majority of work for you. Consecutive dates are merged. As the answer says "The final formatting of the date strings to your desired format is left as a separate exercise.".

Comment: A great thanks and I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd `reduce()` the `values` to an object where you group the data as desired. Then you can output it the way you like.

Date format is done with `new Date()`, this could be improved to group the dates to show eg
`24 - 27` instead off `24, 25, 26, 27`

Example, which outputs only those with a date found, result is:

```
Name#1: 2023-01-23, 2023-01-25 --> Name#2
Name#5: 2023-01-22, 2023-01-23, 2023-01-24, 2023-01-25, 2023-01-26 --> Name#4
Name#6: 2023-01-22, 2023-01-24, 2023-01-25, 2023-01-26 --> Name#3
```

```js
function display() {
    const values = [
        ["Name/Date", "2023-01-22T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-23T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-24T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-25T18:30:00.000Z", "2023-01-26T18:30:00.000Z"],
        ["Name#1", "", "Name#2", "", "Name#2", ""],
        ["Name#2", "", "", "", "", ""],
        ["Name#3", "", "", "", "", ""],
        ["Name#4", "", "", "", "", ""],
        ["Name#5", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4", "Name#4"],
        ["Name#6", "Name#3", "", "Name#3", "Name#3", "Name#3"]
    ]

    const headers = values.shift();
    
    const res = values.reduce((p, c, i) => {
      
        const key = c.shift();
        const replacementNames = c.filter(Boolean).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)[0] ?? 'unkown';
        
        const replacementDates = c.reduce((p, c, i) => {
            if (!c) { return p; }
            let parsed = new Date(headers[i + 1]).toISOString().split('T')[0]
            return [ ...p, parsed ];
        }, []);           
           
        return { ...p, [key]: { replacementDates, replacementNames } };
    }, {});
    
    for (let o in res) {
        if (res[o].replacementDates.length) {
            console.log(`${o}: ${res[o].replacementDates.join(', ')} --> ${res[o].replacementNames}`);
        }
    }
}

display();
```

Comment: This doesn't merge consecutive dates, as in OP's example.

Comment: The contiguous dates are to be shrinked showing first and last date, whereas this code will dump all dates. The example expected strings show just the start and end date if the dates are contiguous (continuous)

Comment: Merge consecutive dates is a major issue here.

Comment: Yea there are tons of way of doing that, like dayjs etc. NOt sure what approch you'd like. To bad I get downvoted while the other asnwer has the same.... so nice

Comment: @0stone0 For the record, my answer _does_ merge consecutive dates into runs. If you look at the output, it says "... through ...".

Comment: It's half grouped, not in a single output... `23, 25-27`

Comment: @0stone0... yes... because if you look at the data, there's a gap in how name#3 is replacing name#6. And as my post says, final formatting is left as an exercise for the reader, because they're not e.g. describing how to format spans between months.